# NNBD: Least upper bound of String and Null

Tags: dart, dart-2, dart-analyzer

Working on a patch for some issues in the Dart Analyzer, I need to understand whether Null itself is considered a nullable type.

Currently, the least upper bound computed by Dart’s type algebra for String and Null is String.

However, in my opinion, the type union of String and Null is a nullable String.

Ticket with patch: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38585 Note that the patch still has a bug in widening T to T? if a closure returns both T and null.

Bonus question (ticket https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38623): Is Null itself a nullable type and should be suffixed with ‘?’?

My opinion as proof by contradiction (LUB is least upper bound function):

- Assume that Null is not nullable.
- That means Null and Null? are different types.
- LUB(T, Null) = T?, i.e. combining T with Null widens T to T?
- Hence, LUB(Null, Null) = Null?
- That violates LUB being reflexive which would mean that LUN(Null, Null) = Null
- Hence the assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart does not, yet, have non-nullable types. So, the type written as `String` *is* a nullable string. The `Null` type is considered a subtype of any type, and therefore the least upper bound of `Null` and (nullable) `String` is (nullable) `String`.

When Dart gets non-nullable types, that will change. Then the type written `String` will be non-nullable, and `String?` will be nullable, and the least upper bound of `Null` and `String` should then (hopefully!) be `String?`. Non-nullable types are not yet available, but they are being designed and are expected to be released ... well, when they are ready.

If you are trying to patch the Dart Analyzer, then you need to be aware of both type systems at the same tiem, because the analyzer has already been modified to recognize some non-nullable types if you pass the proper flags and proper source code.

Comment: I amended the title with NNBD and linked the ticket plus patch. We are already porting a project to NNBD and have a version of the analyzer that treats comments like /*?*/ as ? using a replacing ResourceProvider. This lets us “early adopt” NNBD without breaking the code. Works quite well, but I discovered a few bugs.

Comment: I just added a bonus question: should Null have nullability suffix „question“, is a nullable type.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the best place to get answers to questions about experimental and partially complete implementations of partly specified features ;). The developers of the actual tool are most likely the only ones who know the current state, and everybody else have to guess or read the code like you do. For the specification, the current draft is at https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/nnbd/feature-specification.md#static-errors where it says that `Null` is indeed nullable.

Comment: I understand. However, NNBD is my #1 missing feature in Dart. As said, we are adopting the feature already without breaking our code by introducing them inside comments with a patched Analyzer frontend. When the full Flutter toolchain is ready, we just have to unwrap all the comments. We have other patches, e.g. one that turns operator[] of Map to return K? instead of K.